# Windows phone 8.1 background timer to stop music

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8.1, background-agents, background-task

Hello as part of an app that plays relaxing music in the background using the `BackgroundMediaPlayer`, I would like to implement a way of turning off the music after a set time..

What I was thinking was to have a `TimerPicker` for the user to pick when the music should stop and then add Timer as a supported task type to my MusicBackgroundTask under the Declarations in the appxmanifest.

Then properly in some way use a `ThreadPoolTimer` in my MusicBackgroundTask Windows Runtime Component to stop the music when it ticks, but I really cant find anywhere online that explains how to make timers in a background task work.

So if anyone have a good link that explains or better some working code it would be a great help, thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an MSDN sample that shows an `IBackgroundTask` implementation using a `ThreadPoolTimer` (see SampleBackgroundTask.cs): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9/sourcecode?fileId=43572&pathId=498327315

One potential reason for this not working is if you did not keep a reference to the object returned from `IBackgroundTaskInstance.GetDeferral()` which would cause your background task to complete prematurely after `IBackgroundTask.Run` returns.  The sample linked above does this and I believe this is also required for the BackgroundMediaPlayer Audio task to continue playing music so I would be surprised if you didn't already have this.

Finally, the "Timer" task type in your `MusicBackgroundTask` declaration in the appxmanifest file will have no impact for your usage of `ThreadPoolTimer`.  The "Timer" task type is to allow an `IBackgroundTask` entrypoint to be triggered by `TimeTrigger` and `MaintenanceTrigger` triggers.